# adding multiple content elements to a page?

Tags: entities, nodes, 7

I am coming from TYPO3 and like Drupal a lot so far. Especially how easy it is to define custom content elements with the fields feature.

But what I kind of miss is this:

In TYPO3 you have pages which can be filled with content elements of various kinds (text, text with images, tables, forms,...). I like this a lot. It's versatile and harder to mess something up for the editors compared to simply having a "page" where you have a big text area you have to work in.

What the best way to achieve something similar in Drupal?

Edit:
Here are two example screenshots of the TYPO3 backend:
http://www.aemka.de/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/Backend_2_02.png
http://www.form4.de/typo3temp/pics/faa6f10095.jpg

Yes, it seems like those panels are exactly what I am looking for. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with TYPO3, would you be able to expand a bit more on how they implement the _text, text with images, tables,..._ side of things? I'm assuming by the big textarea you mean the WYSIWYG editor (ckeditor/tinymce/whatever you've installed). Do TYPO3 have extensions for their WYSIWYG editor that allow you to add that sort of structured content, or is the UI provided in some other way? If you could take a screenshot that would be really useful, just upload it to an online service and link to it - someone with a bit more rep will add the image into the question inline

Comment: Actually, I'm gonna take a stab that you might be looking for something like the [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module

Comment: Use Drupal core! You are just describing the Drupal fieldable entities...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for https://drupal.org/project/panels. It gives you the ability to add various types of content.

Comment: Bizarre - we came to that conclusion at exactly the same second in time :)

Comment: Yea I saw you posted after I copy pasted on the page :) lol